# Solution for SQL conditional query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been tasked with coming up with a solution for a problem that was found this morning.  I have a query that I need to do some math with.  I have three pertinent columns.

```
SELECT lQ.[QUANTITY], lQ.[FORM_FACTOR_ID], oQ.[INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGING] 
FROM [dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] as lQ
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ
  ON lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER]
```

I can see myself doing this in a loop easily in languages I know best.  It doesn't seem that looping is a good thing to do in SQL based on some preliminary research so I am reaching out for suggestions.

I need to output a total value which is a conditional sum of `lQ.[QUANTITY]`.  The condition is if `oQ.[FORM_FACTOR_ID]` is equal to 1 then the output for that particular row is equal to the value of `lQ.[QUANTITY]`.  If `oQ.[FORM_FACTOR_ID]` is equal to 2 then if `oQ.[INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGING]` is true, then the output of that particular row in the query is equal to `lQ.[QUANTITY]`.  If the value is false, then the output of that particular row in the query is divided by 2.  The final output needs to be a single integer.

```
QUANTITY    FORM_FACTOR_ID  INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGING
4           2               1
5           1               1
```

I would need a query that outputs the value 7 for the above table.

```
QUANTITY    FORM_FACTOR_ID  INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGING
4           2               0
5           2               0
```

That same query needs to output 5 for the above table.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: using Case in your select?

Comment: Kudos for realizing a loop was a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you just want conditional aggregation -- a `CASE` as an argument to `SUM()`.

If I follow the logic, it would look like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN oq.FORM_FACTOR_ID = 1 THEN lQ.QUANTITY
                WHEN oQ.FORM_FACTOR_ID = 2 AND oQ.INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGING = 1 THEN lQ.QUANTITY
                WHEN oQ.FORM_FACTOR_ID = 2 AND oQ.INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGING = 0 THEN lQ.QUANTITY / 2
            END)
FROM [dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] lQ LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] oQ
     ON lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER];
```

Comment: There seems to be only one condition in which this doesn't behave as expected.  When `INDIVIDUAL_PACKING` is `True` and the `QUANTITY` total is odd, it doesn't round up.  I'll update the main post with this part.

Comment: I've added `CEILING(lQ.[QUANTITY] / 2)` to the third case which should address my odd numbers problem, but I'm still getting 4 (the sum total).  Any ideas?

Comment: @Simon if you read the comment just above yours you'll see I did that already.  The solution is `CEILING(lQ.[QUANTITY] / 2.0)` as 2 by itself is of the integer data type and 2.0 is of the decimal data type.

Comment: @Simon I'm not sure what you're getting at, but again you're trying to post on top of the solution I've already posted.  The problem isn't that `lQ.[QUANTITY]` is an integer.  The problem is because I'm dividing two integers, the resulting solution outputs an integer.  If you change either of the two to a decimal, the answer becomes a decimal, which in turn becomes number I can either `ROUND`, `CEILING`, or `FLOOR` in the way needed.